# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole();
        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation(
          "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.");

    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** exception at the CreateLogger method. If I change .AddConsole(0 to .AddDebug(), it runs without error. So, what I am missing? Do I need to add something in the .config file?